# When using ASP.NET and the new VS2022 live preview for webforms, how to re-enable option to show elements at bottom of designer

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2022

So, when I right now use the new live preview for WebForms (new for VS2022)

(ASP.NET, .NET framework 4.8, WebForms)

Then I see this:

[image]

However, I used to see what was below, and the "elements" would display. That element display works much like the f12 browser tools (and element selector). This in effect is a breadcrumb display and hierarchy of the controls.

So, I used to see what I have below, and you can clearly see the "elements" in visual studio's web form designer.
So, somehow turned off this feature, and wish to turn it back on

[image]

So, the blue arrows shows how this works.

Any ideas how to get this option back?

Comment: Not really an answer, but kinda feel you might be better redirecting this MS Developer community page.  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/suggest

Comment: My post is a bit of a fishing. SO tends to be for coding questions. I am spooling up a VM and installing vs2022 into that. Then I will take screen shots of WHEN I disable the option to get help on how to re-enable. So, I disabled the live preview connection to the browser, and now I can find out how to turn that back on. I been at this for many years, but how to re-enable this option escapes me, and so does using google, or GPT. I simply can't find the answer. I'm always the one answering questions on SO, and if I don't know the answer, then I doubt no one will or does. Lonely at the top!

Answer (score 0):

## Edit: Found the answer

Looks like I had 1 issue that caused this:

My 2nd monitor seems to have a bit of a "sync" issue. (display not updating correctly), so WHEN I did find the correct option, I missed and did not see the changes on that monitor).

Thus my main monitor, I changed the scale from 125% (recomended for laptop monitor) to 100%

Next up, simple toggle the design icon, and the bread-crumbs (elements will now show).

For those who not seen this, you get this effect with the new live preview:

So, we are NOT running code yet, but ONLY using designer.

You get/see this:

[image]

Note how I toggle design mode, and THAT toggles (hides/shows) the very bottom bread crumbs. It was those bread crumbs I could not get to show. Turns out I was toggling that option, but with my laptop resolution at 125%, then on my 2nd larger 24 inch monitor, that bottom part was missing.

However, I most certainly did switch to one monitor, and the issue persisted.

Regardless, it now works, and a "toggle" of the design mode icon thus will toggle the breadcrumbs on the bottom of the designer.